# How to set individual color for every Group in a 2D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do i get the same color for every group A,B,C... ?

this is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data
group_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

data = [
    [0.735721594, 0.619603837, 0.87785673, 0.482125754, 0.0894892, 0.133485767, 0.995450247],
    [0.666117198, 0.52923401, 0.499589112, 0.096963416, 0.308461174, 0.130418723, 0.195501054],
    [0.696378042, 0.437459297, 0.033071186, 0.645614608, 0.99425186, 0.097360026, 0.354376981],
    [0.552392974, 0.668845104, 0.079569268, 0.455465795, 0.353141333, 0.147198273, 0.249947862],
    [0.591065904, 0.34886412, 0.821742243, 0.008845512, 0.259947361, 0.063514992, 0.040540063],
    [0.016209069, 0.092671819, 0.195080351, 0.886493551, 0.745661888, 0.504613173, 0.593546542],
    [0.536218451, 0.466140392, 0.721903277, 0.426671591, 0.648579902, 0.823047029, 0.922809018]
]

# Transpose the data to have groups on the x-axis
data = np.array(data).T

# Create a 2D scatter plot with unique colors for each data point
color_map = plt.cm.get_cmap('tab10', len(group_labels))  # Choose a color map
for i in range(len(group_labels)):
    colors = color_map(np.linspace(0, 1, len(data[i])))
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        plt.scatter(group_labels[i], data[i][j], label=f'Group {group_labels[i]}', marker='o', s=50, c=colors[j])

# Customize the plot
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.ylabel('Y Values')
plt.tight_layout()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

and this is the result:
[image]

How do i get the same color for every group A,B,C... ?

Comment: Do you want "the same color for every group"?  If so, then what do you mean by saying that you "want to change the color of my groups"?

Comment: How do i get the same color for every group? sry

Comment: Change `c=colors[j]` to `c='r'`. Then every group will be red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is to use [seaborn.scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html). I'm using pandas to manipulate the data (melt) and then plotting.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data
group_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

data = [
    [0.735721594, 0.619603837, 0.87785673, 0.482125754, 0.0894892, 0.133485767, 0.995450247],
    [0.666117198, 0.52923401, 0.499589112, 0.096963416, 0.308461174, 0.130418723, 0.195501054],
    [0.696378042, 0.437459297, 0.033071186, 0.645614608, 0.99425186, 0.097360026, 0.354376981],
    [0.552392974, 0.668845104, 0.079569268, 0.455465795, 0.353141333, 0.147198273, 0.249947862],
    [0.591065904, 0.34886412, 0.821742243, 0.008845512, 0.259947361, 0.063514992, 0.040540063],
    [0.016209069, 0.092671819, 0.195080351, 0.886493551, 0.745661888, 0.504613173, 0.593546542],
    [0.536218451, 0.466140392, 0.721903277, 0.426671591, 0.648579902, 0.823047029, 0.922809018]
]

# Use pandas dataframe; melt and then plot
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = group_labels)
df = df.melt(value_vars=group_labels)
sns.scatterplot(df,x='variable', y='value', hue='variable', legend=False )
```

Plot:

[image]